# Картинки и числа Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Вот например, у меня есть приложение которое выводит сумму в результате сложения выбранных чисел (из двух дат) , которая по итоге не превышает *99*. То есть из сложения я вывожу некий процент. Есть картинки (иконки), на которых изображены цифры, от 0 до 9. То есть штук 10 картинок.

Подскажите пожалуйста, с помощью чего мне сделать так, чтобы выводились данные картинки, которое будут синхронизированы с полученной суммой. То есть у меня в сумме получилось, например 55. НО! Чтобы выводились не цифры, а именно картинки(с изображением цифр) с данным числовым значением.

*Надеюсь, понятно объяснил.*

Comment: Что вы пробовали и что не получилось?

Comment: Да в целом ничего не пробовал, так как, не могу ничего толком придумать. Хотя бы просто какой метод,функция или массив можно использовать.Там уже сам разберусь

Comment: А в чем сложность-то ? делаете маппинг ["0", R.dwarable.zero; "1", R.dwarable.one; и так далее], получаете сумму: цифру в строку -> посимвольно получате дравабл идентификаторы. Они уже присваиваются соответствующим свойствам drawable объектов лейаута. Это первое что пришло в голову и может выглядеть костыльно.

Comment: keekkenen. Спасибо большое,попробую.